# Creating a Dynamic object selection/reassignment mechanism for a MetaObject Protocol in Rust

Tags: rust, metaobject, meta-object-protocol

I want to create a way for object functionality to be dynamically altered at runtime in Rust, similar to how MetaObjects are changed in languages like CLISP or Groovy.

The idea is to offer a black box to the user (or other components) through some kind of interface or pointer to a mutable pointer which in turn points to a mutable struct. This way the means of *accessing* the functionality won't change, but the underlying implementation can be changed on the fly (preferably by creating a new struct and then pointing the mutable pointer to it & then destroying the old struct). Currently I'm trying to figure out how to do this while keeping the borrow checker happy.

In short:
{External (immutable) Pointer} -> {Private Mutable Pointer} -> {Mutable (or otherwise replaceable) Struct}

The intended purpose for this is to have a means for an AI or other program to dynamically improve an object or method while maintaining the same interface to the rest of the program so nothing breaks (same inputs & outputs, but the underlying code can change).

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Currently trying to get the borrow checker to go along this while calling 'println!'. Currently getting an error saying that Mobj doesn't implement the Copy trait.

```
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct Mobj {
        str: String
    }

    let mut m_ptr = Mobj {str: String::from("Object 1")};
    let ptr = m_ptr;

    println!("{:?}", m_ptr.str);
    println!("{:?}", ptr.str);

    // Reassign pointer to new object
    let m_ptr = Mobj {str: String::from("Object 2")};
    println!("{:?}", m_ptr.str);
    println!("{:?}", ptr.str); // Call to same, unchanged immutable pointer that points to mutable pointer
    // ^^^^ Still points to old 'Object 1'


    // Now points to the new 'Object 2', but might not be doing exactly what I want it to do.
    let ptr = &m_ptr;
    println!("{:?}", ptr.str);
```

Comment: Multiple parts of the code using an object that can change? Sounds like an `Arc<Mutex<_>>` to me.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the feedback. Currently playing with GPT to see if it gives anything useful. Right now the best it has given is a struct containing RefCell<Vec<T>> to hold a vector of elements that can be added or removed dynamically using borrow_mut().push(element) to add and borrow_mut().get_mut(index).cloned() to remove. 

As with most anything GPT it looks nice but the compiler throws an error because it doesn't implement Clone. So there's a bit to work on.

Comment: `RefCell` is for single-threaded use. Do you have multiple threads?

Comment: @Finomnis Right now I'm just trying to get the functionality down before even thinking of working with multiple threads. Thanks for the answer BTW!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do won't work with normal references.

The biggest issue is the requirement to have an immutable reference to a mutable reference that then does some mutable stuff. If that were allowed, you could duplicate the immutable reference to then get multiple mutable references to the same object at the same time, which is considered undefined behavior.

To achieve that, you need some kind of runtime aliasing check. Depending on your  usecase, this will be either [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) (single-threaded) or [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) (multi-threaded). This creates something called "interior mutability", meaning the runtime conversion from `&` to `&mut`.
If you then also don't want to deal with lifetimes and simply want to use the variable in multiple parts of your program, you could further wrap it in an [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) (single-threaded) or [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) (multi-threaded). This isn't strictly necessary, but in many usecases, those two are used in conjunction.

In my example I assume you have no threads and therefore will use `Rc<RefCell>`.

Further, the usecase of having a fixed set of functionality while having the possibility to replace the actual object that provides said functionality fits perfectly to a [`trait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.trait.html). Then, you can store your object as [`Box<dyn Trait>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) to abstract away the real type.

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

trait MyTrait {
    fn do_something(&mut self);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Mobj {
    str: String,
}

impl MyTrait for Mobj {
    fn do_something(&mut self) {
        println!("Mobj: \"{}\"", self.str);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let shared_obj: Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn MyTrait>>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Box::new(Mobj {
        str: String::from("Object 1"),
    })));

    let second_ref = Rc::clone(&shared_obj);

    second_ref.borrow_mut().do_something();

    *shared_obj.borrow_mut() = Box::new(Mobj {
        str: String::from("Object 2"),
    });

    second_ref.borrow_mut().do_something();
}
```

```
Mobj: "Object 1"
Mobj: "Object 2"
```

Of course you don't necessarily need the `Rc`, you could also do this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let shared_obj: RefCell<Box<dyn MyTrait>> = RefCell::new(Box::new(Mobj {
        str: String::from("Object 1"),
    }));

    let second_ref = &shared_obj;

    second_ref.borrow_mut().do_something();

    *shared_obj.borrow_mut() = Box::new(Mobj {
        str: String::from("Object 2"),
    });

    second_ref.borrow_mut().do_something();
}
```

But your usecase seems complex enough that it might be useful. But decide by yourself ;)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! This really helps clear things up for the foundation of the MOP I'm thinking of building for Rust. The Rc definitely seems like a good idea to add in, especially if arbitrary structs are going to be hot-swapped. The biggest concern was regarding the deletion of the older struct, since I don't want it destroyed before all processes using it had run their course. Still a bit new to Rust so I don't truly know how things like this run under the hood.

Comment: Instead of `Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn Trait>>>`, you can use just `Rc<RefCell<dyn Trait>>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman How do I change its content then? How would I write `*shared_obj.borrow_mut() = Box::new(...)`?

Comment: @MichaelSipos Deletion before everyone is done using it is undefined behaviour, and the Rust compiler guarantees 100% no undefined behaviour (unless you use `unsafe{}` blocks). So there literally is no way that you could program something like that accidentally, the Rust compiler won't let you. That's what I love about Rust, you don't need to concern yourself with those thoughts, the Rust compiler (especially: the borrow checker) will force you to handle those edge cases.

Comment: @MichaelSipos If you haven't yet, I strongly recommend reading the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) and [Rust by example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/). Compared to languages like C/C++, Rust has new concepts that cause frustration if you don't understand them (like the concept of ownership).

Comment: @Finomnis Yeah, you can't do that AFAIK, so if you need that you need `Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn Trait>>>`.

Comment: @Finomnis Funny you mentioned that, as I'm actually looking at the Rust Programming Language book from No Starch Press right now to learn about RefCell on page 334. RefCell definitely looks like a good fit for this. I'm just hope there isn't some weird peril ahead for adding/modifying/removing arbitrary elements to the MetaObject. Apparently the Interior Mutability pattern shifts borrow checking from compile time to run time so I'll see where that goes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MichaelSipos "Interior Mutability pattern shifts borrow checking from compile time to run time" - Yes, exactly. And for multithreading the same thing is called `Mutex`. Also one more hint: Don't really think about `&` as immutable and `&mut` as mutable. It makes more sense if you think about `&` as shared access and `&mut` as exclusive access. Then the 'interior mutability' pattern makes more sense - it's a filter that only allows on access at a time, which converts shared access to exclusive access. Mutability is just the consequence of the rule that only exclusive access allows mutation.

Comment: @Finomnis Interesting observation. I'm also considering using RwLock to ensure multiple read access while enforcing singular write access, since Mutex is said to only allow read access to one caller at a time.

Comment: @MichaelSipos *"I'm also considering using RwLock"* - Don't, unless you have very good reason. `Mutex` is *much* more efficient than `RwLock`.